# Android dynamic onClick buttons from sensor list

Tags: android, list, dynamic, onclick, sensors

i'm having trouble with dynamic buttons from sensor.
As you can see the i get the list of sensor and assign them a button for each of them.
Then i can't make the onClick listener work because for some reason it doesn't fit the "1" a.k.a. "i" that was generated from the loop.

I'm wondering if someone could help me find a way to fix this problem, because i'm quite new and i searched the web for answers but no one else is forced to work with a integer as an ID. Yes, i tired btnTag.setId("btn" + i), but it doesn't acknowledge that..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener, OnClickListener  {

    TextView myTextView;    
    SensorManager mySensorManager;
    TextView status;
    String btn = "button";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mySensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);

        List<Sensor> myList = mySensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_tags);


        for (int i = 1; i < myList.size(); i++) {
                myTextView.append("\n" + myList.get(i).getName());


                Button btnTag = new Button(this);
                btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                btnTag.setText(myList.get(i).getName());
                btnTag.setId(i);
                layout.addView(btnTag);
                ((Button) findViewById(i)).setOnClickListener(this);

            }
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.1:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "button1 is working", 3000).show();
                break;
                }
    }
```

Comment: I even tired putting it in the R file too as a premade button id.

Comment: Have you tried changing `((Button) findViewById(i)).setOnClickListener(this);` to `btnTag.setOnClickListener(this);`?

Comment: Hi CodeMagic, it tired it out but it's the same. I'm having trouble with the OnClick. :(

Comment: I see. You can use `setTag()` in your `loop` and `getTag()` in your `onClick()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're manually setting your ids, you can just do.-

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case 1:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "button1 is working", 3000).show();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did just that in my code and it said "R.id can not be resolved as a variable" :(